# How to turn off shortcuts in tkinter gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def closer(event):
    root.destroy()
root.bind("<F4>", closer)
```

If I press F4 while I click the other window, there is no response, and I must click F4 in the program window that contains the code and press F4 to operate.

What code should I add to turn off in the other windows?
I'd like to turn off the program using the shortcut in another window.

Comment: `root.unbind('<F4>')`?

Comment: I'd like to turn off the program using the shortcut in another window.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Can explain in detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean system-wise hotkey? If yes, try `pynput` module.

Comment: Try change to `root.bind_all("<F4>", closer)`

Comment: I want to turn off my program even if I press F4 when my program and pycharm is on and I am working on the pycharm

Comment: If my program is not active, there is no response even if I press F4.

Comment: You can unbind it with `root.bind("<F4>", lambda e: None)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Also Do Like This:

```
def closer(event):
    root.destroy()
root.unbind("<F4>")
```

The unbind() method removes event handlers from selected elements.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, I understand you are looking for a solution for binding a system-wide hotkey.

That is not possible directly through tkinters `bind` method, you will need an external module. There are several options for this, such as

- [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)
- [system_hotkey](https://pypi.org/project/system_hotkey/)
- [PyHK](https://schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/)

I have personal experience only with the `system_hotkey` module. You could use that by adding the following code. Bear in mind that any hotkey added like this will make the key inaccessible by other programs.

```py
import system_hotkey
hk = system_hotkey.SystemHotkey()
hk.register(['F4'], callback=closer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demonstration of doing it by binding a no-op function to the function key as I suggested in a comment. For testing purposes I've also added a second event handler function  and bound it to <kbd>F5</kbd> which will bind and unbind the handler for <kbd>F4</kbd>.

```
from tkinter import *

UNBOUND, BOUND = 0, 1

root = Tk()

def closer(event):
    print('closer called')
    root.destroy()

def toggle_closer(event):
    global state

    print('toggle_closer called')
    if state == BOUND:
        root.bind("<F4>", lambda e: None)
        print('  F4 unbound')
        state = UNBOUND
    else:
        root.bind("<F4>", closer)
        print('  F4 bound')
        state = BOUND

root.bind("<F4>", closer)
state = BOUND
root.bind("<F5>", toggle_closer)

root.mainloop()

print('Terminated')
```